# NetCDF Library Linkage on Windows with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, netcdf, netcdf4

I'm trying to include/link the NetCDF C library (https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/index.html) into my C++/CUDA project with cmake. I seem to be running into issues, though.

I am on Windows 10 and have installed the NetCDF C libraries for Windows, version 4.7. Including the NetCDF libraries seems to go without a hitch, the problem is in the linking step.

My code that uses the NetCDF library:

```
netcdf_writer.cpp

#ifndef __CUDACC__
//only actually include the NetCDF libraries if we aren't in CUDA
#include <netcdf.h>

#endif

void write_full_netcdf_file(string filename, Configuration cfg) {
    int ncid, x_dimid;

    int retval;

    if ((retval = nc_create(filename.c_str(), NC_CLOBBER, &ncid))) {
        ERR(retval);
    }
    /* Define the dimensions. NetCDF will hand back an ID for each. */
    if ((retval = nc_def_dim(ncid, "x", cfg.nx, &x_dimid)))
        ERR(retval);


}
```

Note that this code is appropriately split into header/cpp files, I've just consolidated here for simplicity.

A truncated version of my CMakeLists.txt file is below. Note that I use VTK's FindNetCDF.cmake: https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/CMake/FindNetCDF.cmake to do the finding.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(cmake_and_cuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")

include(CTest)

#add in all CUDA and C++ files along with their associated headers. 
file(GLOB_RECURSE sources  src/*.cu src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE headers "src/*.h" "src/*.hpp" "src/*.cuh")


find_package(NetCDF 4.7 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${NetCDF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${NetCDF_LIBRARIES})


set (Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS "")
foreach (_headerFile ${headers})
    get_filename_component(_dir ${_headerFile} PATH)
    list (APPEND Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS ${_dir})
endforeach()
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS)

 set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -g")
# We need to explicitly state that we need all CUDA files in the 
# particle library to be built with -dc as the member functions 
# could be called by other libraries and executables

add_executable(foo ${sources})


set_property(TARGET foo
             PROPERTY CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE ${Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE ${LIBS} )
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC NetCDF::NetCDF)
```

When I run cmake, I get the following:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (add_executable):
  Target "foo" links to target "hdf5::hdf5-shared" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:45 (add_executable):
  Target "foo" links to target "hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
...
```

What I've tried:

- I've tried including/linking the HDF5 library explicitly (although NetCDF should provide this already). This results in the same error.
- I've tried explicitly linking the two HDF5 libraries: `target_link_libraries(mac PUBLIC hdf5::hdf5-shared hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared)`. Again, this results in the same error.

Comment: What does `${NetCDF_LIBRARIES}` include? You can print this out with `message(${NetCDF_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: `${NetCDF_LIBRARIES}` is `netcdf`, apparently. Maybe the issue is in my FindNetCDF.cmake, although it appears that the one from vtk is pretty well used.

Comment: It smells like a core of the problem is [netCDFConfig.cmake](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c/blob/master/netCDFConfig.cmake.in) script, which is included into `FindNetCDF.cmake` script with `find_package(netCDF CONFIG QUIET)` line. As far as I understand, netCDF internally is linked with `hdf5`, and this linkage becomes a part of `netCDFConfig.cmake` script. However, the script lacks for  `find_dependency(HDF5)` line. Add this line into the script, e.g. before `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/netCDFTargets.cmake")` line.

Comment: For locate `netCDFConfig.cmake` script for edit, open `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory and find `netCDF_DIR` variable in it. Value of this variable is a directory with `netCDFConfig.cmake` script.

Comment: Alternativly, you may try to add `find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)` into **your** `CMakeLists.txt` and see what happens.

Comment: I think we're rapidly approaching an answer; thanks @Tsyvarev . When I include `find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)` I get a new error, namely that it now can't find `Threads::Threads` . I am digging into the `netCDFConfig.cmake` script now too.

Comment: This is a problem but I don't think it's the problem: it was pulling NetCDF "4.4.1.1" from my anaconda library, I will override this and see if it works.

Comment: @Tsyvarev adding `find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)` and `find_package(Threads REQUIRED)` worked; if you write this as an answer I would be happy to accept. This really shows the issues with including Anaconda libraries in your path, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I am building an application that uses NetCDF. My platform is Windows 10 using a not really up-to-date Msys2. After including the appropriate lines

```
find_package(netCDF REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myapp netCDF::netcdf)
```

I experienced a similar problem as the original poster.
Introducing HDF5 as an additional requirement as suggested by @Tsyvarev, however, solved the problem for me:

```
find_package(netCDF REQUIRED)
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myapp netCDF::netcdf)
```